# Why Is My Count Statement Returning 0 Rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this postgresql syntax

```
CREATE TABLE Testing (
   salesID integer,
   datePO date,
   empID char(10),
   saleDate date
);


INSERT INTO Testing(salesID, datePO, empID, saleDate) VALUES
('11991111', NULL, '234510', '2020-08-20'),
('11992222', NULL, '234510', '2020-08-21'),
('11994444', NULL, '234510', '2020-08-21'),
('86432181', NULL, '841321', '2020-08-25');
```

And I want to run this statement

```
Select
salesID
,datePO
,empId
,saleDate
From Testing
Where saleDate between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-30'
GROUP BY salesID, datePO, empId, saleDate
Having Count(empID) > 1
```

but I get `0` results returned.  Which baffles me because as you see the first three rows of the `Insert` should be returned since they meet the criteria.  What do I need to change so those rows are returned?

If it helps here is a fiddle to my https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sFN1GEEhCh7f6wcFreukhS/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `group by`, so your query is checking where the four keys in the `group by` are the same.

These uniquely identify each row, so no group has more than one row.

You don't really explain the logic you want to implement, so it is hard to offer a suggestion.

Hmmm.  I'm guessing that you want `empId` that appear more than once.  For that, use window functions:

```
Select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by cmpid) as cnt
      from Testing t
      where saleDate between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-30'
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: wow, just learned something new.  I didn't realize a ``Group By`` did that!  And yes, you are correct guessing I want all rows where ``empID`` appears more than once.

Answer (score 1):

If you write every(any) column after group by, it cant group it. If you want singularity try this query than you can understand.

```
Select
empId
,Count(empId)
From Testing
Where saleDate between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-30'
GROUP BY empId
Having Count(empID) > 0
```

Comment: That is what throws me.  I'm used to having to add EVERY field in the ``Select`` to the ``Group By`` or we get error (Microsoft SQL Server background)